# How to group multiple cloud functions into a single project in GCP?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have developed multiple event-driven cloud functions using NodeJS in GCP. Each cloud function has it's own package.json and index.js also there are many custom module (or utilities) file I created as part of each cloud functions.
But these custom modules are redundant across cloud functions i.e., they are repeated in every cloud function.
Now my question is, if I want to make an update/change in any one of the utility file then I must do the same change in all cloud functions individually. Also, what I observed is that package.json has many common dependencies but with different versions. 
To avoid this, I am thinking to group these individual cloud functions into one with only one package.json and single copy of custom modules that can be referred by all cloud functions.
I tried my best to find some useful resource to implement this but couldn't find one.
I referred [this document](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing) and here they mentioned that it's possible to have multiple function entry point ([defined here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing#directory-structure-nodejs:%7E:text=The%20code%20in%20your%20main%20file%20must%20define%20your%20function%20entry%20point%20and%20can%20import%20other%20code%20and%20Node.js%20modules%20as%20normal.%20The%20main%20file%20can%20also%20define%20multiple%20function%20entry%20points%20that%20can%20be%20deployed%20separately.%3Cbr/%3E))

Can anyone let me know how do I group multiple functions to one?

---

Current project structure:

```
Root-directory-
  -dir_cloudFunction_A
    -index.js
    -myModule.js
    -package.json
  -dir_cloudFunction_B
    -index.js
    -myModule.js
    -package.json
```

Currently I have two cloud functions under a root directory, cloud function A is in dir_cloudFunction_A directory and cloud function B is in dir_cloudFunction_B directory.
Each cloud function has index.js, myModule.js and a package.json
Now I have myModule.js (custom module) in each directory (same copy). Problem with this approach is that, when I need to make any changes in myModule.js, I must ensure that it is updated in all of it's copy wherever this has been referred.
To avoid this issue, I am suggested to share this myModule.js in one place and use it in 'n' number of cloud functions in root directory.
But I'm not sure how can I do this.

Comment: This question is very abstract and difficult to answer. It would be easier if you show exactly what you have now, and what you tried that doesn't work the way you expect. Then maybe someone can see what you've done wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: Note the docs you linked say "If you are thinking of grouping multiple functions into a single project, be aware that every function may end up sharing the same set of dependencies. However, some of the functions may not need all of the dependencies. Where possible, we recommend splitting up large multi-function codebases and putting each function in its own top-level directory as shown above, with its own source and project configuration files. This approach minimizes the number of dependencies required for a particular function, which in turn reduces the amount of memory your function needs.

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson I updated the question with few more details. Please have a look and suggest me some solution.